# authorization error while calling adapter from iphone

Tags: android, ios, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

When i make an adapter call from iPhone i am getting following error in a server log , while in android its working fine.

```
SRVE0190E: File not found: /authorization/v1/clients/instance
[ERROR   ] FWLSE0048E: Unhandled exception caught: SRVE0190E: File not found: /authorization/v1/clients/instance
java.io.FileNotFoundException: SRVE0190E: File not found: /authorization/v1/clients/instance
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.extension.DefaultExtensionProcessor.handleRequest(DefaultExtensionProcessor.java:528)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:127)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:88)
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter$1.execute(AuthenticationFilter.java:217)
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationServiceBean.accessResource(AuthenticationServiceBean.java:76)
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:222)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:194)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:85)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:968)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1056)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:4553)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.handleRequest(DynamicVirtualHost.java:301)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:954)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.run(DynamicVirtualHost.java:266)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink$TaskWrapper.run(HttpDispatcherLink.java:776)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Comment: nagative voters have a courtesy to explain the reason for the same

Comment: i found the reason over here `https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/190421/i-am-running-a-mobilefirst-app-and-i-am-seeing-a-f.html` but dies anyone know the solution

Comment: The question you linked to states that this may happen if your app, which is based on MFPF 7.0, attempts to connect to a MFPF Server that is < 7.0. Is this your scenario? What is your scenario?

Comment: why are you not replying back?

Comment: After researching and referring your comments i come to know that my client build was created in worklight 7.0.0 and the server was in 6.3 and then i download the 6.3 studio from direct download link provided by you and this is how i was able to resolved issue , many thanks !

Comment: you are expected to resolve questions. Please do not keep this question unanswered - either remove it, or provide your comment as an Answer to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As my mobile build was created in Mobile first 7.0.0 and my server version was 6.3.0 , i was getting `File not found: /authorization/v1/clients/instance` error.

i was able to resolved it by referring @Idan's comment , i downloaded the mobile first eclipse studio version from link that he has provided earlier [Mobile First 6.3](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/products/en/MobileFirstPlatform/mobilefirst_studio_plugin_6.3.0.0.zip)